# changing post type in loop query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

i created a template named "taxonomy-myword.php" and i am tring to print posts related to this custom category. Unfortunately, my posts are affected with a custom post type too.

I tried the right way :

```
function customize_customtaxonomy_query ( $query ) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('business') );
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_query' );
```

and the bad way :

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'business' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Unfortunately, only the second code works. I'm wondering why...

Comment: Are you creating a secondary query?

Answer (score 0):

To have the first code block to work on a *secondary* query, you'd need:

```
function customize_customtaxonomy_query ( $query ) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('business') );
    // return $query; // not necessary; actions do not return anything
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_query' );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

And you should remove it afterwards so that it doesn't interfere with other loops.

To have that filter work on the main query it needs to be applied before the main query runs, which means (usually) it needs to be in `functions.php` or a plugin file.

However, if you are creating a secondary Loop (can't tell if you are) then the filter looks like overkill. Just pass the arguments you want. Untested, but something like this:

```
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'business' ) );
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That is a lot of guessing but I hope it helps.